# Ubuntu 22.04.3 thinks my USB-connected phone is empty, but it used to see everything fine

Tags: usb, kubuntu, android

## Kubuntu 22.04.3 thinks my USB-connected Samsung Galaxy S22 is empty, but it used to see everything fine.

There are two settings I can choose on my phone in USB Settings:

USB controlled by

- Connected device
- **This device**

Use USB for

- **Transferring files / Android Auto**
- USB Tethering
- MIDI
- Transferring images
- Charging phone only

I bolded the ones I've selected, and to the best of my knowledge, I haven't changed them since. As you can imagine, Samsung has pushed updates to my phone and I've happily updated Kubuntu dozens of times in the interim.

If memory serves, it used to be that when I plugged it in, it would auto-mount under one name (Device Name), then when I accepted the connection on the phone, it would re-mount as SAMSUNG_Android. Then I could browse my files as normal.

Now Dolphin just reports it's empty. For the record yes, the phone has files in it. More than it used to, in fact.

I tried plugging it into my Lubuntu laptop to rule out the phone, and it works fine there.

Comment: How is it mounted? On the command line (Ctrl-Alt-T), `mount` will show you. Which groups are a member of? `id`.Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.